How to use "would rather"
While using the structure "Would rather" if the subject is the same in both clauses and we wish to refer to the present or future time we use present simple or continuous for instance "I'd rather do it now". If we wish to refer to the past we would use present perfect and said "I'd rather have done it then". If we have different subjects we use either past simple or continuous while refering to the present or future time or past perfect while refering to the past
Let's go to my questions about that structure. I'm going to list them.

Let's consider this example. It is about future and the subject is the same. "I'd rather do it when she arrives. Can we use here perfect infintive to emphasize that the action will have been done before she arrived and write "I'd rather have done it when she arrives"?

Now , we have different subjects but still I want to refer to the future. "I'd rather you helped me when she arrives". Can we use past perfect to show help will be done before her arrival and say "I'd rather you had helped me when she arrives"?



In case 1, "I'd rather do it when she arrives" means you'd prefer not to start doing it until she arrives. "I'd rather have done it when she arrives" means you'd prefer to have started and finished before she arrives.

For case 2, Nobody would ever be likely to say "I'd rather you had helped me when she arrives". Native speakers (well, this one, at least) don't care whether you say "I'd rather you helped me when she arrives" or "I'd rather you help me when she arrives". Imho, anyone who wants to argue strenuously in favour of Past or Present (or "unmarked infinitive"?) there is a pedant. Both forms occur (as does "I'd rather he help me when she arrives", though that's certainly less common).

@FumbleFingers thank you. So, we can say that 2 with past perfect is correct but unlikely and means that "help" occured before her arrival, yes?

'Correct' by what standards?  If you wanted someone to help you to finish a task before the arrival of a visitor, you would say "I'd rather you helped me before she arrives", NOT "I'd rather you had helped me when she arrives".

@KateBunting you think my example is wrong and we would not use past perfect with 'would rather" unless we want to talk about the  past?

I think you're trying to apply inappropriate semantics to the word helped/help in contexts like #2. It's just referring to a future hypothetical situation. English only really has 2 tenses, Present and "Not-Present". We just use helped there because it's "not-present". Nobody thinks in terms of "past in the future" or anything like that. It's obviously not Present (here, now), because that's what we've currently got. We're talking about what we'd rather have, so we have to use the "not-present" verb form. Which looks just like the Past, but we don't think that.

So we don't use past perfect there even to stress to completion before another event, correct?

FumbleFingers had already told you that 'Nobody would ever be likely to say' it. It may be 'correct' in that it doesn't violate any grammatical rule, but that combination of tenses is totally unidiomatic.
